# to the beginning after fork

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm confused because because in this code.  I'm not sure that after fork new process moves to beginning because it should not, there should be only one `do`. The rule is that new process begins after fork instruction, not from the beginning but there is something wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf(" do ");
    if(fork()!=0) printf("ma ");
    if(fork()==0) printf("to \n");
    else printf("\n");
}
```

result

```
do ma 
do ma to
do to
do
```

what I think it should be 
do ma 
to

Comment: The output is buffered. And the buffer is copied to the forked process.

Comment: But it should start after next instruction, please could you write something more Eugene Sh.?

Comment: Two duplicates are for your reference.

Comment: Why are you calling `fork` twice?

Comment: It was excercise to understand this better neverthless problem solved :)